# HttpSession with Spring 3 MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I want to use HttpSession in Spring 3 MVC. I have searched all the web and got this solution at http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?98850-Adding-to-stuff-to-the-session-while-using-ResponseBody

Basically, my application auto authenticates user by getting *winId* and authorizes through LDAP (it's an intranet site).

Here is the flow of the application:

1. User enters Application URL (`http://localhost:8082/eIA_Mock_5`) it has a welcome page (index.jsp)
2. index.jsp gets *winId* through jQuery and hits login.html (through AJAX) and passes windowsId
3. login.html (Controller) authenticates through LDAP and gives back 'Valid' String as a response
4. JavaScript, upon getting the correct response, redirects/loads welcome page i.e. goes to `localhost:8082/eIA_Mock_5/welcome.html`

Now, I have filter associated with it, which checks if the session is valid for each incoming request. Now the problem is even though I set data on to HttpSession, yet the filter or any other controller fails to get the data through session as a result it doesn't proceeds further.

Here is the code. Could you suggest what is wrong actually?

**Home_Controller.java**:

```
@Controller
public class Home_Controller {

    public static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(Home_Controller.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/welcome"})
    public ModelAndView loadWelcomePage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        ModelAndView mdv = new ModelAndView();
        try {
            /*HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            UserMasterBean userBean = (UserMasterBean)session.getAttribute("userBean");
            String userName = userBean.getWindowsId();
            if(userName == null || userName.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {   
                mdv.setViewName("homePage");

                System.out.println("Unable to authenticate user ");
                logger.debug("Unable to authenticate user ");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Welcome User "+userName);
                logger.debug("Welcome User "+userName);
                */
                mdv.setViewName("homePage");
            /*}*/

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            logger.debug("inside authenticateUser ",e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mdv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String authenticateUser(@RequestParam String userName, HttpSession session)
    {
        logger.debug("inside authenticateUser");

        String returnResponse = new String();
        try {
            logger.debug("userName for Authentication " + userName);
            System.out.println("userName for Authentication " + userName);

            //HttpSession session  =  request.getSession();

            if (userName == null || userName.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                returnResponse = "Invalid";
            else
            {
                System.out.println("uname " + userName);

                String ldapResponse = LDAPConnectUtil.isValidActiveDirectoryUser(userName, "");

                if (ldapResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
                {   
                    returnResponse="Valid";

                    System.out.println(userName + " Authenticated");
                    logger.debug(userName + " Authenticated");

                    UserMasterBean userBean = new UserMasterBean();
                    userBean.setWindowsId(userName);

                    //if(session.getAttribute("userBean")==null)
                    session.setAttribute("userBean", userBean);
                }
                else
                {   
                    returnResponse = "Invalid";

                    //session.setAttribute("userBean", null);

                    System.out.println("Unable to Authenticate the user through Ldap");
                    logger.debug("Unable to Authenticate the user through Ldap");
                }

                System.out.println("ldapResponse " + ldapResponse);
                logger.debug("ldapResponse " + ldapResponse);

                System.out.println("returnResponse " + returnResponse);
            }

            UserMasterBean u = (UserMasterBean)session.getAttribute("userBean");
            System.out.println("winId " + u.getWindowsId());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.debug("Exception in authenticateUser ", e);
        }
        return returnResponse;
    }
}
```

**Filter**:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
{
    System.out.println("in PageFilter");
    boolean flag = false;
    HttpServletRequest objHttpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;
    HttpServletResponse objHttpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
    HttpSession session = objHttpServletRequest.getSession();
    String contextPath = objHttpServletRequest.getContextPath();

    String servletPath = objHttpServletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath(objHttpServletRequest.getServletPath());

    logger.debug("contextPath :" + contextPath);
    logger.debug("servletPath :" + servletPath);
    System.out.println("in PageFilter, contextPath :" + contextPath);
    System.out.println("in PageFilter, servletPath :" + servletPath);

    if (servletPath.endsWith("\\") || servletPath.endsWith("/") || 
        servletPath.indexOf("css") > 0 || servletPath.indexOf("jsp") > 0 || 
        servletPath.indexOf("images") > 0 || servletPath.indexOf("js") > 0 || 
        servletPath.endsWith("index.jsp") || servletPath.indexOf("xls") > 0 || 
        servletPath.indexOf("ini") > 0 || servletPath.indexOf("login.html") > 0 || 
        /*servletPath.endsWith("welcome.html") ||*/ servletPath.endsWith("logout.do") )
    {
        System.out.println("User is trying to access allowed pages like Login.jsp, errorPage.jsp, js, images, css");
        logger.debug("User is trying to access allowed pages like Login.jsp, errorPage.jsp, js, images, css");
        flag = true;
    }

    if (flag == false)
    {
        System.out.println("flag = false");

        if (session.getAttribute("userBean") == null)
            System.out.println("yes session.userbean is null");

        if ((session != null) && (session.getAttribute("userBean") != null))
        {
            System.out.println("session!=null && session.getAttribute(userId)!=null");

            logger.debug("IF Part");

            UserMasterBean userBean = (UserMasterBean)session.getAttribute("userBean");
            String windowsId = userBean.getWindowsId();

            logger.debug("User Id " + windowsId + " allowed access");
            System.out.println("User Id " + windowsId + " allowed access");
            flag = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("else .....session!=null && session.getAttribute(userId)!=null");
            logger.debug("Else Part");
            flag = false;
        }
    }

    if (flag == true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("before chain.doFilter(request, response)");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                objHttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(contextPath + "/logout.do");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("before sendRedirect");
            objHttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(contextPath + "/jsp/errorPage.jsp");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    System.out.println("end of PageFilter");
}
```

**index.jsp**:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    //alert("inside s13");
    var WinNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
    var userName = WinNetwork.UserName;
    alert(userName);

    $.ajax({  
        url: "login.html",  
        data: "userName="+userName,
        success: function(result) {
            alert("result == " + result);
            if (result == "Valid")
                window.location = "http://10.160.118.200:8082/eIA_Mock_5/welcome.html";
        }
    });
</script>
```

*web.xml* has a filter entry with URL pattern as `*`
I am using Spring 3 MVC.

Comment: You seem to be using the session primarily for access control / permissions. Wouldn't spring security be a better solution?

Comment: I am totally new to spring security and hence i am relying native session..also could you point what is wrong over here ?? i dont seem anything has been missed out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem in ajax call and setting windows.location after that.

Make sure you set cookie enabled. If you don't do this, your ajax request will lead to new session every time.

When you do `window.location = url` and this url differ than your current url, it also lead to new session, because cookie is domain related, and you changed domain, for example from `localhost` to `10.160.118.200`.

For each request output sessionid and compare it with previous request. It helps find when  session was recreated.

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4794179/1516873) can help.

Comment: Yes you are right......i completely missed it....
as i was abt to deploy on production...and thats why changed the url...after rekeeping the same URL, it worked..you are a life saver
thanks appreciated